# When, if ever, does $(I + H)/H \not\cong I/H$? (Equivalently, when $I/(H\cap I) \not\cong I/H$?)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, abelian-groups, quotient-spaces

> The quotient $G /H$ of two abelian groups, $H \subseteq G$, is defined as the set of all cosets of $H$: $$G/H := \{ g+H: g \in G \} \,. $$
>
> **Question:** How does this definition depend on the fact that $H \subseteq G$? It seems like it only depends on addition of elements of $G$ and elements of $H$ being defined.
>
> More specifically, let's say we have another subgroup of $G$, call it $I$, and possibly $H \not\subseteq I$.
>
> **1.** Nevertheless, addition of elements of $H$ and $I$ is well-defined, so why is the set $$"I/H" := \{ g+H: g \in I \} $$ not well-defined as a group?
>
> **2.** If it is well-defined as a group, why is not equal (isomorphic) to $(I+H)/H$ in general?

---

**Attempt:** The fact that all groups are abelian simplifies things inasmuch as we are guaranteed that all subgroups are normal subgroups. But we still need to check in this case whether addition in $"I/H"$ is well-defined, since possibly $H \not\subseteq I$.

So let's say that $x_1, x_2 \in I$ are such that $x_1 + H = x_2 +H$, and $y_1, y_2 \in I$ are such that $y_1 +H = y_2 + H$. Then $(x_1 +H) + (y_1 +H) = (x_2 +H) + (y_2 +H)$ if and only if $$(x_1 + y_1) + H = (x_2 +y _2) + H \iff (x_1 + y_1) - (x_2 + y_2) \in H \,.$$ But $(x_1 + y_1) - (x_2 + y_2) = (x_1 - x_2) + (y_1 - y_2)$. And $(x_1 - x_2) \in H$ since $x_1 + H = x_2 + H$, and also $(y_1 - y_2) \in H$ since $y_1 +H = y_2 +H$, and since $H$ is a group, $(x_1 - x_2), (y_1 - y_2) \in H \implies (x_1 +y_1) - (x_2 + y_2) = (x_1 - x_2) + (y_1 - y_2) \in H$.

In other words, addition in $"I /H"$ does seem well-defined. Also, $"I/H"$ is closed under inverses, because $I$ is. And since $"I/H"$ is a subset of $G/H$ closed under addition and forming inverses, it should be a subgroup of $G/H$. Therefore, at no point does the assumption $H \subseteq I$ seem necessary.

**Motivation:** I started thinking about this when trying to show that the quotient $R/I$ of a graded ring $R$ by a homogeneous ideal $I$ is again a graded ring, because the first thing I wrote down for the possible grading of $R/I$ was $\oplus_{d \ge 0} R_d/I$, before realizing that, in general, $I \not\subseteq R_d$. This led me to try $\oplus_{d \ge 0} (R_d +I)/I$, which worked.

But now I think I may have been led to the right answer for the wrong reason, since I can't justify my original claim that $I \not\subseteq R_d$ implies that $R_d /I$ is not well-defined.

**Note:** [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633354/why-can-quotient-groups-only-be-defined-for-subgroups) is related, but is even more general, since it does not restrict to abelian groups. However, neither of the two answers to that question (one deleted) explain why the subset condition is necessary.

Comment: Given $G$ and $H$ you have a surjective map from $G$ to $G/H$ and what you define is simply the image of $I$ under this map, which is a subgroup of $G/H$ and indeed isomorphic to $(I+H)/H$.

Comment: In short, whenever $H \subseteq I$, since $H+I = I$, then $(I+H)/H = I/H$, and whenever $H \not\subseteq I$, the conventional definition of $I/H$ is not well-defined/does not exist, and then the definition of $I/H$ I give above (the image of the surjection you mention) is equal to $(I +H)/H$ (which always makes sense in the conventional sense, since clearly $H \subseteq I+H$), so we _always_ have that $(I+H)/H = I/H$. I was incorrectly confusing this with the question of when $(I + H)/H \cong I$, which occurs when $I+H = I \oplus H$.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft How do I show that $I/H$ and $(I+H)/H$ are isomorphic? I wrote out the definitions of both once and got that they were the same, but I thought I was making a mistake -- was I not?

Comment: They are not only isomorphic they are equal.

Comment: @DerekHolt Is that still true even when $H \not\subseteq I$? I know this is a really dumb/stupid/basic question, but that's why it's all the more important to me that I am sure I have the right understanding (because if I'm wrong about this, then I'll be wrong about everything that depends on it, which is a lot, because it is so basic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've addressed the more general noncommutative version of your question in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633354/why-can-quotient-groups-only-be-defined-for-subgroups), so here I'll address your motivation question directly:

The issue with "$R_d/I$", given that $I$ is not a subgroup of $R_d$, isn't one of well-definedness. It's just nonstandard terminology. The set of cosets of $I$ by elements of $R_d$ is, in fact, *equal*, both as a set and as a group, to $(R_d+I)/I$.

Moreover, $(R_d+I)/I$ is isomorphic to $R_d/(I \cap R_d)$, so that gives two ways to describe the group using standard notation. The fact that "$R_d/I$" is nonstandard is simply an emphasis of the fact that every "quotient" of $R_d$ *can* come from a normal *sub*group of $R_d$.

Comment: Oh... yes I think I get it now -- since $"R_d/I"$ can be expressed by $R_d/(I \cap R_d)$, there is no need to confuse things by introducing a new concept of quotient groups for groups which are not subgroups. Thank you for explaining and confirming this for me.