# How does the nth Symmetric Power result from the quotient of the group of rank N tensors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, quotient-group, symmetric-algebra

In "Basic Algebra" by Knapp, the author gives this definition of the symmetric power over a vector space E over a field K and tensor algebra T(E) where I is the ideal generated by all $u \otimes v - v \otimes u$ in T(E) where $u,v \in E$:

S<sup>n</sup>(E) = T<sup>n</sup>(E) / (I $\cap$ T<sup>n</sup>(E)

My question is how does this quotient result in S<sup>n</sup>(E)?

For example in the case of n = 2, T<sup>2</sup>(E) would be the tensors of rank 2 and I $\cap$ T<sup>2</sup>(E) would be the antisymmetric tensors of rank 2 (could be represented as antisymmetric matrices).
My understanding is that the quotient algebra generated should consist of the cosets of I $\cap$ T<sup>2</sup>(E) in T<sup>2</sup>(E) and I'm not sure how these cosets give us S<sup>2</sup>(E).

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: What is $S^n(E)$ for you? In the book, $S^n(E)$ is *defined* as $T^n(E)/(T^n(E) \cap I)$.

Comment: Right it is defined that way but the most important property to me is that an element of $S^n(E)$ is that it is symmetric under the exchange of any two indices and I don't understand how that property results from the definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I see it is this. $T(E) = \bigoplus_{n \geq 0} T^n(E)$ is a non-commutative graded $K$-algebra. The two sided ideal $I$ generated by $(x \otimes y - y \otimes x)$ for $x,y \in E$ is generated by homogeneous elements so it is a homogeneous ideal of $T(E)$.

We know that [the quotient of a graded ring by a homogeneous ideal has a natural grading](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/969894/quotient-ring-of-a-graded-algebra-with-respect-to-a-graded-ideal) so that we can write $T(E)/I = \bigoplus_{n \geq 0} S^n(E)$ where we *define* $S^n(E)$ to be the homogeneous elements of degree $n$ in $T(E)/I$. By the linked question this is indeed the quotient $T^n(E)/(I \cap T^n(E))$. Hence we can realize $S^n(E)$ as the vector space generated by cosets $v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k + I$. Then, $$(v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k + I) - (v_2 \otimes v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k + I) = (v_1 \otimes v_2 - v_2\otimes v_1) \otimes v_3 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n + I = I$$ since $(v_1 \otimes v_2 - v_2\otimes v_1) \in I$. As such, $$v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k + I = v_2 \otimes v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k + I$$ so that $T^n(E)/(J \cap T^n(E))$ has the characteristic property you'd expect from $S^n(E)$, that you can switch around any two tensors.

Comment: Thanks, this explains exactly how the cosets lead to the property that elements of $S^n(E)$ are symmetric. My only other point of confusion is if $v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_k + I$ is an element of $S^n(E)$? If so isn't the ideal "I" causing that element to not be symmetric (since I is antisymmetric)?

Comment: @user36249 No problem! It is because $I$ acts like $0$ in the quotient $T(E)/I$, and $0$ is trivially symmetric.